# Intel 3945ABG DPC spikes (audio stutter, mouse) in Windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, cpu-usage, dpc

As reported by many users, Intel WiFi chips such as 3945ABG and the later 4965 may experience CPU spikes due to DPC activity.

This is typically experienced as:

- Audio stuttering.
- Uninterrupted dumping of 5010 events with NETWLV64.SYS as source. (Probably NETWLV32 also, depending on architecture).

Event information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727742(v=ws.10).aspx

Event data that appears:

> The description for Event ID 5010 from source netwlvXX cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> \Device\NDMPx

I've personally been bugged with this event on Windows 8 and 8.1 only with default Microsoft drivers, and with newer Intel drivers.  My system is a Lenovo R61i with updated Core2 Duo CPU, 3GB RAM and i945 system chipset. An old and standard configuration.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is driver-related.

The solution is to install old Vista drivers. I finally fixed it with Intel 3945ABG version **11.5.1.8.**

No more CPU spikes, DPC latency and derived problems such as audio crackling.

Link to driver, in this case provided by HP:

ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp38001-38500/sp38437.html
ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp38001-38500/sp38437.exe

Install them by unzipping with 7Z or WinRAR, and forcing Device Manager to use those drivers instead of the (surely) newer ones you got installed by Microsoft.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These drivers work well also in Windows 10 (up to 1903 for sure).