# Windows 10 wifi cannot connect - Intel pro 3945abg wireless card

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-driver

I try to connect to the network on windows 10, but it always says "could not connect to network".

The intel website says that the pro 3945abg is not supported for windows 10.

How do I get this working?

EDIT:

Things I have tried so far:

> I downloaded the following driver:
>
> Intel® PROSet/Wireless Basic Enterprise for IT Administrators: Windows
>   7 64-Bit*
>
> File name: Wireless_14.3.1_Ds64.zip
>
> Version: 14.3.1 (Previously released)
>
> Date: 03/12/2012
>
> Size: 7.61 MB Language: English Operating Systems: Windows 7, 64-bit*
>
> https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21049
>
> This doesn't entirely fix the problem. Restarting the computer causes
>   the problem to reoccur. running iprodifx.exe provided in the file will
>   bring the connection back, but I dont know what is causing it to loose
>   the settings.

Also:

> uninstall the driver for the wifi card, so that it is forced to use the generic driver

After trying #2, it appears to work for a bit, but soon reverted to being unable to connect after restarting or resuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my current solution:

- Plug in a network cable
- open device manager, network devices and open the properties for the intel wireless card
- on the driver tab, click uninstall, tick the box to delete the driver when prompted
- close the device dialog, and reopen it once the machine has found it again (you may need to click "search for devices")
- Open the device properties again, this time click the option to search for drivers from the web.

I then followed Bigbio2002's recommendation of disabling "Allow the computer to turn off this device".

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [this older driver](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp38001-38500/sp38437.exe) (from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/687513/intel-3945abg-dpc-spikes-audio-stutter-mouse-in-windows-8-1), not sure if the issues are related, but it's worth a try).

Or try installing [this newer driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/25140/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-IT-Admins?httpDown=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F25140%2Feng%2FWireless_18.11.0_De132.zip), suggested in this much more [relevant thread](https://communities.intel.com/thread/77854).

Also, go into Device Manager after installing the driver of your choice, go to the Power Management tab on your device, and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device". That seems to be a universal recommendation for troubleshooting Intel WiFi cards.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, on two different Windows 8 laptops (one Dell Inspiron 15, one ASUS) recently upgraded to Windows 10.  I thought it was the drivers, and maybe they have something to do with it, but my workaround is really simple: **change the WPA key to be all-numeric.**  That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Download the drivers from the link below and update the drivers from device manager manually.

http://whp-hou4.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp54501-55000/sp54791.exe

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this script:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe restart-netadapter -InterfaceDescription 'Intel(R) Pro/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection' -Confirm:$false

automatically using the 'Hibernate trigger' freeware program set to run on startup. Paste the above line/script into  'path you want to execute on resume' in the prog.
This seemed to fix the problem on windows 10 x64 with the old intel 3945ABG for me.  None of this is my work, see references for explanations.
References:
http://www.desimonesystems.com/suspendtrigger/
https://help.downtownworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024693851-My-internet-or-WiFi-gets-disconnected-after-Sleep-in-Windows-10-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to network settings by clicking wireless icon in task bar
2. Go to adapter settings all the way down and click diagnose this connection you will be connected after you get FIX message

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows 10 supplied driver for the Intel Pro 3945ABG wireless card on my Dell laptop, often results in an inability to connect after a start or restart.  When this happens, I disable the network card via Device Manager and then re-enable the network card.  After that, the device connects and functions correctly.